# Weird layout inflation crash after Android Studio and gradle version upgrade

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I have recently upgraded my Android Studio and Gradle versions (see below for exact versions and context). Immediately after the upgrade the app started crashing (100% of the time) while trying to inflate a layout with the following root cause:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3.5"
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:608)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:133)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:375)
    at com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView.init(ParallaxScrollView.java:45)
    at com.nirhart.parallaxscroll.views.ParallaxScrollView.<init>(ParallaxScrollView.java:28)
    at net.chinookbook.android.widget.CBParallaxScrollView.<init>(CBParallaxScrollView.java:19)
```

The widged that fails to be inflated looks like this in the layout xml:

```
<net.chinookbook.android.widget.CBParallaxScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:parallax_factor="3.5">
```

The styleable declaration is

```
<declare-styleable name="ParallaxScroll">
    <attr name="parallax_factor" format="float" />
    <attr name="alpha_factor" format="float" />
    <attr name="inner_parallax_factor" format="float" />
    <attr name="parallax_views_num" format="integer" />
    <attr name="circular_parallax" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

with the following generated resources:

```
public static final class styleable {
    public static final int[] ParallaxScroll = { 0x7f040028, 0x7f04007c, 0x7f040101, 0x7f040172, 0x7f040173 };
    public static final int ParallaxScroll_alpha_factor = 0;
    public static final int ParallaxScroll_circular_parallax = 1;
    public static final int ParallaxScroll_inner_parallax_factor = 2;
    public static final int ParallaxScroll_parallax_factor = 3;
    public static final int ParallaxScroll_parallax_views_num = 4;
}
```

The **ParallaxScrollView.init()** method is this:

```
protected void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typeArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ParallaxScroll);
    this.parallaxFactor = typeArray.getFloat(R.styleable.ParallaxScroll_parallax_factor, DEFAULT_PARALLAX_FACTOR);
    this.alphaFactor = typeArray.getFloat(R.styleable.ParallaxScroll_alpha_factor, DEFAULT_ALPHA_FACTOR);
    this.innerParallaxFactor = typeArray.getFloat(R.styleable.ParallaxScroll_inner_parallax_factor, DEFAULT_INNER_PARALLAX_FACTOR);
    this.numOfParallaxViews = typeArray.getInt(R.styleable.ParallaxScroll_parallax_views_num, DEFAULT_PARALLAX_VIEWS);
    typeArray.recycle();
}
```

And now, for the weird part observed while debugging the code: Stopping the debugger at the line:

```
typeArray.getFloat(R.styleable.ParallaxScroll_parallax_factor, DEFAULT_PARALLAX_FACTOR);
```

I can see that the method is about to be invoked like this (this is what the debugger evaluates) - which looks correct: **typeArray.getFloat(3, 1.9F)**. But then I step in the method

```
public float getFloat(@StyleableRes int index, float defValue)
```

and to my surprise, **index = 0** and **defValue = 1.9**. The app doesn't crash here, it does so at this line:

```
typeArray.getInt(R.styleable.ParallaxScroll_parallax_views_num, DEFAULT_PARALLAX_VIEWS)
```

which should be invoked with **typeArray.getInt(4, 1)**, but when I step in the method

```
public int getInt(@StyleableRes int index, int defValue)
```

again, to my surprise the parameter values are **index = 3** and **defValue = 1**. This time, the app will crash because the styleable resource with the index 3 is the **parallax_factor** which is defined as 3.5 and cannot be read as an int.

So, my question is, how can it look like a method is going to be invoked with some (primary) values, and then actually be invoked with other values. What am I missing? **Note:** ParallaxScrollView is imported from an external library

================================================
Environment:

Android Studio: **3.1.2**
Gradle: **3.1.2** (upgrade from 2.3.3)
Gradle wrapper: **4.4** (upgrade from 3.3)

compileSdkVersion **27**
buildToolsVersion **27.0.3**
minSdkVersion **16**
targetSdkVersion **27**
multiDexEnabled **true**
com.android.support:multidex:**1.0.3** (upgrade from 1.0.1)
com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:**1.0**

Comment: https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll/issues/62